# Algoritmo PHP 1,2,3,4 = 1 + 2, 2 + 3, 3 + 4

Tags: php, algoritmo

Por exemplo, eu tenho esse array:

```
$Ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Abaixo está o resultado que eu gostaria de obter:

```
$Pair [0] = 1 + 2;
$Pair [1] = 2 + 3;
$Pair [2] = 3 + 4;
```

Comment: Tentou alguma coisa já?

Comment: $b = array("a" => 1+2, "b" => 2+3, "c" => 3+4);
echo "soma(b) = ".array_sum($b)."\n";

Comment: estou com dificuldades em separar as duplas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é o ideal, nem se essa pergunta tem dup, mas uma maneira que pode fazer:

```
$Ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
for($i = 1; $i < count($Ids); $i++)
{
    echo $Ids[($i-1)]." + ".$Ids[($i)]."<br/>";
}

/* Imprime:
 * 1 + 2
 * 2 + 3
 * 3 + 4
 */
```

Se quiser jogar a soma em um novo array:

```
$Ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$newArray = array();
for($i = 1; $i < count($Ids); $i++)
{
    $newArray[] = $Ids[($i-1)] + $Ids[($i)];
}

print_r($newArray);
/* Imprime:
 * Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 )
 */
```

Comment: Obrigado !! Me ajudou muito

Answer (score 3):

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/V5nZEJ)

```
$Ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$result = count($Ids);

for ($i = 0; $i < ($result-1) ; $i++) {
   echo "\$Pair [".$i."] = ".$Ids[$i]. "+" .$Ids[$i+1];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Ajudou muito